# How to remove the address bar on non-Secure http page

Tags: https, window, microsoft-edge, regedit, group-policy

I try to remove the address bar on EDGE Win10,
I can remove the address bar by installing a test page as an EDGE app,
but if the page is non-secure HTTP the address bar remains.
As you can see in this test:
[test with HTTP and HTTPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QkTF.png)

How can I prevent EDGE to insert the non-Secure warning / address bar within specific HTTP contents?
Please note that HTTP content is inside INTRANET as web applications.
I should try regedit first to design the policy later.
Please could you help me about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide the address bar in any way if it's through Group Policy or the registry. Also, it is not recommended to do it. Users should see what URL they are browsing. Otherwise, it may cause security issues.

If a website doesn't have a valid certificate. The information sent to and from it is not secure and can be intercepted by an attacker or seen by others. There's a risk to your personal data when sending or receiving information from this site. In my opinion, users should know if a site is at risk to decide whether to continue accessing it. Otherwise，as mentioned above, it may cause security issues.

Therefore I don't think your requirement can be achieved. Maybe you could refer to this doc: [Securely browse the web in Microsoft Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/securely-browse-the-web-in-microsoft-edge-c7beb47a-de9e-4aec-839d-28224a13a5d2)

Comment: Hi Xudong Peng, I have to avoid the top bar only for a web app within the intranet, so no security issues, with edge: // flags I can avoid security warnings for the specific source, it works, but the bar remains perhaps if the address changes the bar shows the change..

Comment: If you must hide the address bar, you can try to use kiosk mode. Please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode#kiosk-mode-digitalinteractive-signage), which contains simple examples.